# PostgresSQL incompatible query between version 10 and 14

Tags: sql, postgresql, alembic

I have the following statement, which runs fine on PostgresSQL version 10

```
LINE 1: UPDATE tablename SET "cliPrefix"=encode(digest(gen_random_uuid()::text, 'sha512'), 'hex');
                                                ^
```

But on PostgresSQL version 14 this line gave me the error:

> No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

How to fix this?

Comment: The digest function is provided by the extension [pgcrypto](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html)  - did you install that?

Comment: Good catch, I will check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if exists the required extension (pgcrypto)

```
select * from pg_extension;
```

if not

```
create extension pgcrypto;
```